# Move value in every second row to a new column, Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a data set, as shown below, in col A of my spread sheet and I need to now move the percentage value to col B on the same row as the name.

```
  A        
1 John     
2 100%       
3 Mike      
4 100%     
5 Paul
6 100%
7 Ken
8 100%
```

I need to shift every second row to a new column so it should look like this

```
   A    B
1 John 100%
2 Mike 100%
3 Paul 100%
4 Ken  100%
6 John 100%
7 John 100%
```

I have tried a few different approaches but I cannot get it to work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Include some of the code that I had  tried, I am using a reg. expression to filter out some other data and then I need to do the shift on the percentage values.

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sortSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var lastRow = sortSheet.getLastRow();
var searchData = sortSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).clear({formatOnly:true})
    .setNumberFormat('@STRING@').getValues(); 

var regExp = new RegExp ('^[0-9]{2} [A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{4}$');

   for(var y =searchData.length - 1; y >= 0 ; y--) {

       if(regExp.test(searchData[y])) {

 var rowIndex = (y); Logger.log("Row index" + rowIndex)
                sortSheet.deleteRow(rowIndex + 2).deleteRow(rowIndex + 1);

 }
}

var searchData2 = sortSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues(); 
var regExp2 = new RegExp ('^[0-9]{2}%$');

for(var x =searchData2.length ; x >= 0 ; x--) {

    if(regExp2.test(searchData[x])) {

      var getPercentage = new Array;
      var rowIndex2 = (x); Logger.log("Row index" + rowIndex2)
      var temp = searchData2[x];
      getPercentage.push([searchData2]); Logger.log(getPercentage)

 }
}
    var paste = sortSheet.getRange(1, 2, getPercentage.length,
             1).setValues(getPercentage)
}
```

This is not the exact code as I deleted before I posted this question.

Please feel free to get me some suggestions as to how I could improve my code. (I just started learning Javascript 2 weeks ago)

Comment: Why don't you share some of your approaches?

Comment: Please share your last tries, so we can see that you have made some efforts.. After all, this is a Q&A site, not a code writing site...

Comment: Code added. I didn't add it in the first place as it didn't work at all and I knew what I needed to achieve was relatively simple for someone experienced. I didn't want to waste someone else's time reading through useless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short:

declare 2-dimensional Array with needed length (which is length of your array divided by 2).

loop and put every 2nd element into [x][1] and all other elements into [x][0]

```js
var sort = function(arr) {
  var b = new Array(arr.length / 2)
  for (i=0; i <3; i++)
    b[i]=new Array(1);
  
  arr.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
   if(index % 2 == 0 || index == 0) {
     b[Math.floor(index / 2)][0] = value;
    } else {
     b[Math.floor(index / 2)][1] = value;
    }
  });
  return b;
}
```

Here i go with a quick and dirty approach. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your answer and I know I wouldn't have figured it out.. I having trouble integrating it with my code that I have in the OP because I don't understand variables with functions and parameters.. Could  you please suggest how I could integrate it with my code? Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula on column B and populate automatically as necessary

```
=indirect(ADDRESS(ROW() * 2 - 1,COLUMN()-1) )
```

And this one on column C and populate automatically as necessary

```
=indirect(ADDRESS(ROW() * 2,COLUMN()-2) )
```

This is for the case, your data is on column A and at the end your result will be on B and C

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I need to do this trough a script without using formulas.